# Is there any way to allow upload of files whose name contains the "#" character without changing the name?

Tags: file-upload

When using sharepoint to upload a file, the file name can not contain several characters.

> The file name is invalid or the file is empty. A file name cannot contain any of the following characters: \ / : * ? " < > | # { } % ~ & .

But our files-name contain a lot of `#` characters and we do not want to change the files' original names.

Is there any way to make it so that files whose names contain the character `#` can be uploaded to SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only way i see you being able to do this is with a custom application that uploads them to SharePoint and handles the names. should be pretty easy to build